# How to use async/await to get input from user but wait till entire condition statement is read before resolving?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I created a function that prompts the user for a URL, then validates that the entered input is actually a URL. The issue is, when I call this function from my other function, I have been able to get it to wait for user input before but it doesn't go through the entire condition statement before returning the url.

How do I use promises/async/await to wait till my requestSiteURL() function has completed its condition statement, before setting the variable in getURL()?

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   output: process.stdout,
});

// request url from user in command prompt
const requestSiteURL = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readline.question('Please type url: ', async (url) => {
      if (validUrl.isUri(url)) {
        readline.close();
        resolve(url);
        // if user types no, then use base url
      } else if ('No' || 'no' || 'NO') {
        url = URL;
        resolve(url);
      } else {
        reject(
          console.log(
            'Please type in a valid URL or type "no" to use base url.'
          )
        );
        requestSiteURL();
      }
    });
  });
};

// grabs all urls from original link and returns array
const getURLS = async () => {
  let url = await requestSiteURL();
  url = deleteFowardSlash(url);
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const data = res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const urlQueue = [];

    // finds all absolute links and pushs to urlQueue array
    $("a[href^='http']").each((i, elem) => {
      let link = $(elem).attr('href');
      //checks to make sure link isnt any duplicate links in urlqueue array
      link = deleteFowardSlash(link);
      uniqueLinkChecker(link, urlQueue);
    });
    return urlQueue;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return response.status(400).send(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: setting which variable in getURL(S)?

Comment: the variable set is url

Comment: This `else if ('No' || 'no' || 'NO') {` is just a wrong conditional.  Perhaps you mean `else if (url.toLowerCase() === 'no') {`?

Comment: And, `return Promise.resolve().then((resolve, reject) => ` should be `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => `.  `Promise.resolve()` does return a resolved promise that you can call `.then()` on, but it does NOT pass two arguments to the `.then()` handler.  Instead, you need to use the `new Promise()` constructor.

Comment: Please do NOT edit fixes into question.  That changes your whole question and invalidates answers that people have already given you.

Comment: oh okay, sorry, didnt know that

Comment: What exactly is the failure condition?  Does it immediately return every time, or only after an incorrect url is entered?

Comment: so with richytong's answer, if I enter something like 'po', I get 'unhandled promise rejection warning'

Comment: Because you have no handler for a rejected promise from `let url = await requestSiteURL();`.  Put a `try/catch` around that.  And, your `else if` condition is wrong.  And, you resolve with an empty URL but never check for that in the caller.  This code needs lots of fixes.

Comment: I changed else if statement, and I didn't include entire code, I have a baseurl that does have a URL already. I'm sorry, my actual script is long so I didn't include all of it just the part that is broken. I tried wrapping the let url = await requestSiteURL() but get same error, same if I put it in the promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a matter of syntax. Here I switched the original line to use the Promise constructor correctly. [Promise mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
// request url from user in command prompt
const requestSiteURL = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readline.question('Please type url: ', async (url) => {
      if (validUrl.isUri(url)) {
        readline.close();
        resolve(url);
        // if user types no, then use base url
      } else if (url.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
        url = URL;
        resolve(url);
      } else {
        console.log(
          'Please type in a valid URL or type "no" to use base url.'
        )
        requestSiteURL().then(resolve);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Edit: Adding an async/await version. Basically I think you don't ever have to reject. I edited the above to not reject as well. Also I'm assuming `URL` is the default url (this conflicts with the global [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) namespace, just for the record)

```js
// request url from user in command prompt
const requestSiteURL = async function () {
  const url = await new Promise(resolve => {
    readline.question('Please type url: ', resolve)
  })
  if (validUrl.isUri(url)) {
    readline.close()
    return url
  } else if (url.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
    return URL
  } else {
    console.log('Please type in a valid URL or type "no" to use base url.')
    return requestSiteURL()
  }
}
```

Comment: so I made this change, and it does prompt me from the other function but doesn't ever go through the conditional statements. If I write 'potato' it still accepts that

Comment: maybe check `validUrl.isUri`. That's the only other condition I see besides the correct one.

Comment: so if I write a valid URL with this, I get the correct output but otherwise, I am getting the error that I have an unhandledpromiserejectionwarning

Comment: Added an async/await version, also made the first one stop rejecting upon closer inspection.

Comment: this worked, I put my URL default url into my function as well so that its not global. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it doesn't look like your 'else' condition will wait at all.  You reject the promise and recursively call `requestSiteURL()`, but do nothing with the promise that is returned.  This will ask the question again, but the calling function has no way to access that promise.  The original promise that was returned has already been rejected.  The new promise is not referenced anywhere, so when resolve or reject is called for the second time, there is no code to access the result.

If you want your code to fail and reject the returned promise, then you shouldn't call it again in the else statement.

If you do want the one function to keep asking the question until a valid answer is entered, you could fix that issue by encapsulate your code in a function and keep calling it on an error until it resolves with the original 'resolve' parameter of the promise you return.  It doesn't seem like readline.question() takes an async function either:

```js
// request url from user in command prompt
const requestSiteURL = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const askQuestion = () => {
      readline.question('Please type url: ', (url) => {
        if (validUrl.isUri(url)) {
          readline.close(); // close readline here?
          resolve(url);
        } else if ('No' || 'no' || 'NO') {
          url = URL;
          // don't close readline here?
          resolve(url);
        } else {
          console.log(
            'Please type in a valid URL or type "no" to use base url.'
          );
          // call askQuestion() again until we resolve with something
          askQuestion()
        }
      });
      
      // call askQuestion() the first time
      askQuestion();
  });
};
```

Comment: the code I added doesn't include my entire script, I can include it, it's just really long.